# Problem with yahoo search

Tags: search

In my website if a browser has not javascript enabled then I redirect it to a javascripterror.html page.When i search my website on yahoo search then it always shows that javascript error page in its search result.I think that's hapenning because yahoo slurp has its javascript disabled,Is there any way by which Yahoo search result can show my index page in its search results.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068571/do-search-engines-process-javascript