# Is jQuery execute by search engine like Google,Yahoo,bing?

Tags: jquery, seo, meta-tags

if we set meta tag using jQuery in

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 });
```

will this work with SEO  for search engines like Google,Yahoo,Bing etc.?

Comment: jQuery is run by your browser. If you want to set the meta tag by jQuery the tags will change for the user site[I dont even know if that is doable...], your site's server side wont change..

Comment: @prachi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068571/do-search-engines-process-javascript have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlikely. The search engines usually don't run scripts.

Comment: Google improved the JS boting support for some basic searches like execution of links (for example.) Still Google is very secret about what the bot actually processes and understands. Most of other search engines don't understand JS, but it's a story in process. http://www.forbes.com/sites/velocity/2010/06/25/google-isnt-just-reading-your-links-its-now-running-your-code/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, thanks for the link. I'm aware of that, which is why I didn't answer with "no"...